# c# INotifyPropertyChanged como funciona la propiedad nameof

Tags: c#, .net, binding

Estoy usando **INotifyPropertyChanged**  y quiero hacer un binding , pero me encontre con que la hora levantar el binding con los cambios de la UI cuando uso el set de la siguiente manera  `OnPropertyChange("CardOnUsing")`  , nome funciona. Que diferencia hay entre hacer un set con **nameof** , cuando uso este el binding funciona perfecto, Alguien sabe a que se debe?

```
public class CardModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public bool CardOnUsing
    {
        get => _cardOnUser;
        set
        {
            _cardOnUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CardOnUsing));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: como definiste el evento OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: @gbianchi listo edite la pregunte

Comment: en tu caso, debes mandar el nombre de la propiedad... que seria CardOnUsing... o sea tu llamada seria OnPropertyChanged("CardOnUsing"); probaste de esa forma?

Comment: @gbianchi si claro

Comment: y asi funciona.. la pregunta entonces es que hace nameof? te fijaste en la documentacion? devuelve en string el nombre de la clase que pasas... o sea.. hace lo mismo...

Comment: Osea si deberian hacerlo lo mismo pero si le pasaba `"CardOnUsing"` no me renderizaba la UI

Comment: Es exactamente lo mismo, solo que con nameof, usas el intellisense para no errarle. La diferencia que si podes encontrar y te va a fallar es si llamas al metodo `OnPropertyChanged` antes de setear el valor. Y hay otra forma de realizarlo con CallerMember que este infiere quien lo llama y no tenes que pasar el nombre de la variable

Comment: El nameof hace el reemplazo al momento de compilar, tienen lógicamente el mismo efecto, pero es muy útil para determinar cuantas veces usas ese recurso en el intellisense.